# Is DC resistance always higher than AC

Tags: power

My power professor has asked us to explain why DC resistance is always higher than AC resistance. Is it? In all of my researching on the internet, I keep getting that AC resistance is higher, thanks to the skin effect. Is it possible that DC resistance would be higher, or is my professor getting a little too advanced in age?

Comment: 1. AC resistance is an improper term for impedance. 2. Did you professor provide any more details/further clarification to this question? (e.g. across a single component, in the context of a wire, etc?) Because an ideal inductor has zero DC resistance, and a frequency dependent, non-zero impedance, which contradicts your professor's statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, he didn't. He's known for being incredibly vague with his questions. That's also why I'm confused. I intend to ask him about it tomorrow, but I was hoping someone here could shine some light on this. I suspect it is intended to be with regards to a transmission line.

Comment: If he's talking about a transmission line then AC impedance at high frequency can be very high (open circuit) or very low (short) at certain points depending on the inductance, capacitance, resistance, frequency of the signal and other such things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the bottom line is that it's not really about EE but some crank prof.

Comment: @Andyaka I do not think it is off-topic, the basis of AC versus DC impedance in components or transmission lines is about EE in many of its incarnations. I do agree that closing is in order, as it is -unclear what is being asked- seemingly not just to us.

Comment: @Asmyldof this has been covered elsewhere in a few questions and the only reason it is being asked now is because the op is impatient about getting an answer. He's already done the research and, that would be enough, but it's really all about his cranky prof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your professor is messing with you, if he means in general (as in any DC resistance compared with any other AC resistance), No. However, having said that, if he's referring to a specific component, that changes things a little. With a wire, DC will always be lower due to the skin effect (as you correctly surmised), this has an effect even at mains frequencies (50Hz has a skin depth of about 1/2" I think). With an inductor this is doubly true because the impedance of the inductor also goes up with frequency (inductance is a resistance to *current* change so it becomes more resistive the higher the frequency). Now with something that has lots of capacitance, things get more complicated, an ideal capacitor has a infinite DC resistance (two plates with no physical connection cannot pass a DC current) but a capacitor resists *voltage* changes so at AC it behaves like a resistance that gets smaller as the frequency goes up. But unless you're dealing with capacitors, in general, DC resistance beats out AC resistance as the lower of the two.

Answer (score 1):

The professor is pulling your leg as both ac and dc resistance can be adjusted, its just that it takes different techniques to do so. DC resistance is normally adjusted by logarithmic or linear potentiometers, assuming you do not want a simple fixed value resister.
 But you will find you cannot get a resistance less than zero, even if it is 0.001 ohm, which is a common value for current sensing. AC resistance is changed by an adjustable inductor or changing the frequency through a fixed-value inductor.
 What the professor might be referring to is that an inductor can create a negative voltage swing, even when fed positive pulses. When the pulse is turned off, the magnetic field it generated collapses back into the windings, but of opposite polarity. It will have the same amount of current as the positive pulse. It's apparent positive resistance would become negative for a brief period.
 If the negative return pulse is not clamped with a diode, it can damage the circuit. A meter would show negative inductance at that point, which is why inductance is measured with precision sine waves.
 The skin effect (higher resistance) only occurs at high frequencies, above 50MHZ especially. AC impedance makes sure the AC 'resistance' (not really a good term for HF AC) is dominate by a large margin. At GHZ frequencies most all of the signal is riding the surface of the wire or trace to avoid the much higher resistance deeper into the wire/trace.
 Some boards such as those used for Radar have the traces coated with silver, which is a better conductor than copper. The silver is then coated in gold or polyurethane to prevent tarnishing.
 I could write a books worth of the details of AC vs. DC behavior but that is beyond the scope of this forum. Surf the internet for more info. There is no end to what you can learn just on AC vs. DC behavior alone.

Comment: The cranky professor might want the students to relate the problem to a particular component which in this case will be a leaky capacitor. Its DC resistance surely will be higher but not infinite and ac resistance will be anyhow lower than that of DC even at few hertz..!!

Comment: @soosaisteven. I agree with that all the way. There is some 'lost-in-translation' here as to what the professor is really looking for, and the student/OP has to read between the lines to clue us in. A more detailed question would have helped guide the answers better. This one is splitting hairs a bit, and too broad.